# How to remove only one of multiple key value pairs with the same key using URLSearchParams?

Tags: javascript, webapi, urlsearchparams

I have an url in this form: `https://www.example.com?tag[]=mountain&tag[]=hill&tag[]=pimple`

Now I want to remove one of these, let's say `tag[]=hill`. I know, I could use regex, but I use `URLSearchParams` to add these, so I'd like to also use it to remove them. Unfortunately the `delete()` function deletes all pairs with the same key.

Is there a way to delete only one specific key value pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
const tags = entries.getAll('tag[]').filter(tag => tag !== 'hill');
entries.delete('tag[]');
for (const tag of tags) entries.append('tag[]', tag);
```

Comment: Yes, that'll work fine, thank you! Still strange that there really is no built-in way to do this as with get and getAll. Feels like an oversight, it can't be that uncommon of an usecase.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just add it to the prototype of URLSearchParams so you can always easily use it in your code.

```
URLSearchParams.prototype.remove = function(key, value) {
    const entries = this.getAll(key);
    const newEntries = entries.filter(entry => entry !== value);
    this.delete(key);
    newEntries.forEach(newEntry => this.append(key, newEntry));
}
```

Now you can just remove a specific key, value pair from the URLSearchParams like this:

```
searchParams.remove('tag[]', 'hill');
```

Comment: That's a really neat idea, I'll do that if I need that more than once in my code. Thank you!